# Vim has different behaviour for clojure files

Tags: filetype-clojure

In particular, I noticed that the `w` (words forward) behaves differently for `.clj` files, which is pretty frustrating.

Assume we are editing the following text and the cursor currently is placed at the first character.

`abc.abc`

If we press press`w` while editing a `.clj` file, the cursor jumps to the last character.

On the other hand, if the text is in some file without the clojure extension, the cursor jumps to the `.`-character, like expected.

I disabled all plugins and removed my `.vimrc` to verify that this is a native behaviour. Can anybody reproduce and perhaps explain with a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see `:help iskeyword` and check with `:verbose set iskeyword?`:

```
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,?,-,*,!,+,/,=,<,>,.,:,$
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/clojure.vim
```

To set your own options you need to create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/clojure.vim`:

```
setlocal iskeyword-=.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this. I looked through the files and noticed that all lisps have their keywords defined similarly. I am interested in knowing the reason for this

Comment: just guessing but probably because of https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_symbols